# How to set Userform Controls?

Tags: excel, vba, text

So I am currently trying to create a universal variable that while it loops changes values based on textboxes and labels of the userform "Timeline".
TimeLineBox is the universal textbox value that I am trying to change based on Num or Number value.

Unfortunately, it is telling me that I need an object and then when I set them as textbox and label it says the object has not been set.

```
TimelineBox1 = Timeline.TextBox1.Value
TimelineBox2 = Timeline.TextBox2.Value
TimeLineBox3 = Timeline.TextBox3.Value
TimeLineBox4 = Timeline.TextBox4.Value
TimeLineBox5 = Timeline.TextBox5.Value
TimeLineBox6 = Timeline.TextBox6.Value
TimeLineBox7 = Timeline.TextBox7.Value
TimeLineBox8 = Timeline.TextBox8.Value
TimeLineBox9 = Timeline.TextBox9.Value
TimelineLabel1 = Timeline.Label1.Caption
TimelineLabel2 = Timeline.Label2.Caption
TimeLineLabel3 = Timeline.Label3.Caption
TimeLineLabel4 = Timeline.Label4.Caption
TimeLineLabel5 = Timeline.Label5.Caption
TimeLineLabel6 = Timeline.Label6.Caption
TimeLineLabel7 = Timeline.Label7.Caption
TimeLineLabel8 = Timeline.Label8.Caption
TimeLineLabel9 = Timeline.Label9.Caption

Do While Num < 10
    Dim TimelineBox As TextBox
    Dim TimelineLabel As Label

    TimelineBox = "TimelineBox" & Num
    TimelineLabel = "TimelineLabel" & Num
    MSNum = "MS" & Num1
    MSName = "MS" & Num1

    If TimelineBox.Value <> "" Then
        MSNum = TimelineBox1.Value
        MSName = TimelineLabel1.Value
        Num1 = Num1 + 1
    End If

    Num = Num + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Textbox` object you need to use the keyword [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement).

On top of that, it looks like you are trying to set it equal to a `String`.

If you need to loop controls you could try looping all the controls in your userform:

```
Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control
For Each Ctrl In Form.Controls
   If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" then
       '... Do something with your textbox control
   End If
Next Ctrl
```

Comment: Sp I think you maybe on track I am hoping to have a variable who's first part stays the same and the second part changes this makes up the textbox(n) string. So how would I be able to do that with my current code?

Comment: I'm confused by your question? Could you give more examples and include them in an [edit] your question.